# Generic auto-increment foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm writing sql scripts which I would like to run across platforms (mostly mysql and postgres). The problem I see is I cannot arrive at a common one for auto-increment primary keys which are used as foreign keys. Is there a way to do this ?

```
table t1 ( column c1 )
table t2 ( column c2 )
```

c1 is auto increment and c2 is a foreign key referenced on c1.

I tried keeping c1 as SERIAL and c2 as bigint/bigint unsigned/numeric , but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Really, it is futile to try to get SQL code to work across multiple database platforms.  There are just too many variations on the language.

In fact, the syntax for a stored procedure differs significantly between the two.  So, you are going to have to write separate scripts for each database you want to support.